# Label with double quotes produces error "Invalid Label" in browser

Tags: javascript, json

I started getting errors in my browser, parsing JSON return data from the server. At first I thought it is something specific to my data, but even something silly like

```
{"a": 1}
```

results in the error "invalid label" in Firefox and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in Chrome. When changing it to

```
{a:1}
```

(i.e. removing the double quote around the label) it works fine. However, I am sure that even with the double quotes, it is valid JSON (and [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) agrees with this).

The workaround I have seen is to surround the JSON object with brackets like so:

```
({"a":1})
```

and this works from the browser console, but not when I change my server data (which is responding to a JSONP call) and I can't change it in the browser either, because I am using a library (Dojo) and I don't have the opportunity to intercept the return data before it is parsed.

**UPDATE**

I found a bug in my server code where I am not wrapping the data in a JS function for the JSONP response. This has fixed the problem, and I subsequently need to delete this question. Apologies, and thanks for the responses though.

Comment: To make matters worse, I am certain this worked before, but I cannot explain how or why.

Comment: Please show how you are parsing the JSON. Double-quotes are _required_ for valid JSON key names, but I think the problem is you are doing a JSONP call so the client-side code is expecting to see some JS it can execute. It sees the { as the beginning of a block of code, not the start of an object literal, so then when it sees the colon it thinks the thing before it is a label (such as you could use with a continue or break statement). Putting the whole thing in parens means it is interpreted as an expression. JSONP and JSON don't work the same way.

Comment: My apologies, but I found out that I have a bug in my server code, whereby the data is not being wrapped in a function call for JSONP responses as it should be. I am going to delete this question as a result. Thanks nonetheless for your time and effort and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"a": 1}
```

standing alone is not json, it's a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Where `"a":` would be a jump [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) for continue. And such labels are written without `"`.

Whereas `({"a":1})` is an expression. And as such `{"a": 1}` will get parsed as json.

Comment: Did I use the term "label" incorrectly? Is "key" the correct term?

Comment: @mydoghasworms Sorry, can't follow what you mean?

Comment: In the example {a:1}, is a called a "key" or a "label"?

Comment: If written as: `{a:1}` it's called a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). If written as: `({a:1})` (and as such, used as an expression) it's [property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Property_names).

Comment: It's a "label" because the whole thing is not being treated as an expression that is an object literal, it is being interpreted as a block (like an if or for block without the "if" or "for" keyword). That is, the term "label" has nothing to do with objects. If it was an object literal it would be a "property name", or, more informally, "key".

Comment: My apologies, but I found out that I have a bug in my server code, whereby the data is not being wrapped in a function call for JSONP responses as it should be. I am going to delete this question as a result. Thanks nonetheless for your time and effort. I do +1 your response though.